# How can I make an array of data from an arbitrary vector over 2d gridded data?

Tags: python, bilinear-interpolation

I have a gridded data set of latitude longitude and overtop of each of those points I have a temperature creating a contour map. Over top of this gridded data set I have multiple vectors that point in different directions over this contour map. What I want to do is create a 1d array of temperature data that extends out from the direction of the vector to the end of the gridded data box. I have no idea how to do that. I would imagine I need to use some bilinear interpolation method.[This image shows what my data looks like when plotted with cartopy. Gridded temperature data with a line of vectors over top.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqGiK.png)

Comment: How is your data structured? Do you have a callable that returns the temperature for a given point? Is the vector field simply a 3-dimensional NumPy array?

Comment: All of the data is obtained from netCDF files.                                                    sst = d.variables["analysed_sst"][:][0, ::-1, :]  
lon = d.variables["lon"][:]
lat = d.variables["lat"][::-1]